# Traffic going from only IP

Tags: networking, apache-httpd, routing, reverse-proxy

On my VM i have one interface with IP 192.168.22.10 and then i created Interface alias(sub interface) with IP 192.168.22.11.

each IP will host one Virtual Host on port 443 which will send the traffic to backend application server (Apache Reverse Proxy), Now if i try to access the Vhost configured for IP 192.168.22.10:443 i can access it from outside but the Vhost configured for IP 192.168.22.11:443 i can't access it.

running tcpdump shows traffic is going though 192.168.22.10

#### ip addr

```
1: lo: <LOOPBACK,UP,LOWER_UP> mtu 65536 qdisc noqueue state UNKNOWN group default qlen 1000
    link/loopback 00:00:00:00:00:00 brd 00:00:00:00:00:00
    inet 127.0.0.1/8 scope host lo
       valid_lft forever preferred_lft forever
    inet6 ::1/128 scope host
       valid_lft forever preferred_lft forever
2: ens192: <BROADCAST,MULTICAST,UP,LOWER_UP> mtu 1500 qdisc mq state UP group default qlen 1000
    link/ether 00:50:56:aa:36:1d brd ff:ff:ff:ff:ff:ff
    inet 192.168.22.10/24 brd 192.168.22.255 scope global noprefixroute ens192
       valid_lft forever preferred_lft forever
    inet 192.168.22.11/24 brd 192.168.22.255 scope global secondary noprefixroute ens192
       valid_lft forever preferred_lft forever
    inet6 fe80::250:56ff:feaa:361d/64 scope link
       valid_lft forever preferred_lft forever
3: virbr0: <NO-CARRIER,BROADCAST,MULTICAST,UP> mtu 1500 qdisc noqueue state DOWN group default qlen 1000
    link/ether 52:54:00:12:25:ce brd ff:ff:ff:ff:ff:ff
    inet 192.168.122.1/24 brd 192.168.122.255 scope global virbr0
       valid_lft forever preferred_lft forever
4: virbr0-nic: <BROADCAST,MULTICAST> mtu 1500 qdisc pfifo_fast master virbr0 state DOWN group default qlen 1000
    link/ether 52:54:00:12:25:ce brd ff:ff:ff:ff:ff:ff
5: ens224: <BROADCAST,MULTICAST,UP,LOWER_UP> mtu 1500 qdisc mq state UP group default qlen 1000
    link/ether 00:50:56:aa:d2:84 brd ff:ff:ff:ff:ff:ff
```

## Route information

#### route -n

```
Kernel IP routing table
Destination     Gateway         Genmask         Flags Metric Ref    Use Iface
0.0.0.0         192.168.22.254  0.0.0.0         UG    100    0        0 ens192
192.168.22.0    0.0.0.0         255.255.255.0   U     100    0        0 ens192
192.168.22.0    0.0.0.0         255.255.255.0   U     100    0        0 ens192
192.168.122.0   0.0.0.0         255.255.255.0   U     0      0        0 virbr0
```

#### ip route

```
default via 192.168.22.254 dev ens192 proto static metric 100
192.168.22.0/24 dev ens192 proto kernel scope link src 192.168.22.10 metric 100
192.168.22.0/24 dev ens192 proto kernel scope link src 192.168.22.11 metric 100
192.168.122.0/24 dev virbr0 proto kernel scope link src 192.168.122.1
```

I checked netstat and it showed that 192.168.22.11 on port 443, so i add below lines in ssl.conf file

```
Listen 192.168.22.10:443 https 
Listen 192.168.22.11:443 https
```

and now netstat is showing

```
tcp 0 0 192.168.22.11:443 0.0.0.0:* LISTEN 117421/httpd
```

but traffic is still going through 192.168.22.10

Comment: It was not listening but i enabled it now "Listen 192.168.22.10:443 https
Listen 192.168.22.11:443 https " in ssl.conf file and netstat is showing "tcp        0      0 192.168.22.11:443       0.0.0.0:*               LISTEN      117421/httpd" but traffic is still going through 192.168.22.10

Comment: i added the changes in question section, Thanks

Comment: You can try to run `ip route del 192.168.22.0/24 and you will be using the other ip but that is not a great solution

Comment: i delete the "ip route del 192.168.22.0/24" but it cameback on network restart, i think it is bound to ens192:1

Comment: Ah, didnt mention that you need to run the command every time you want to do it, so it is not permanent. While there are ways on doing that i dont know much in this aspect. You can use a systemd job that waits until network.target and in that way make it work

Answer (score 0):

Ok, i got no help but no issues, Figured it out my self. Posting answer for others who find themselves in same problem.

Issue was related to routing.

```
"ip route add 172.16.5.20 via 192.168.22.254 dev ens192 src 192.168.22.11"
```

It will add the route in routing table

```
│Kernel IP routing table
│Destination     Gateway         Genmask         Flags Metric Ref    Use Iface
│0.0.0.0         192.168.22.254  0.0.0.0         UG    100    0        0 ens192
│172.16.5.20     192.168.22.254  255.255.255.255 UGH   100    0        0 ens192
│192.168.22.0    0.0.0.0         255.255.255.0   U     100    0        0 ens192
│192.168.22.0    0.0.0.0         255.255.255.0   U     100    0        0 ens192
│192.168.122.0   0.0.0.0         255.255.255.0   U     0      0        0 virbr0
```

But it will not persist across reboot or service restarts

So add the following lines in /etc/sysconfig/network-scripts/ifcfg-inteface_name

```
"172.16.5.20 via 192.168.22.254 dev ens192 src 192.168.22.11"
```

Now on restarts path will persist

Ofcourse make appropriate firewall changes (Firewalld/Iptables)